# Check if stream is on or off TWITCH API using PHP

Tags: php

The following `if`always return `"Stream is Online!"`, even when `"Stream is Offline!"`

Could anyone point me the error?

```
    <?php
    $opts    = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => "GET",
            'header' => "Client-id: clientidhere\r\n" . "Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json\r\n"
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $file    = file_get_

contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/somestreaming', false, $context);
$json    = json_decode($file);


if (($json->stream === "NULL") || ($json->stream === "null")) {
    echo "Stream is Offline!";
} else {
    echo "Stream is Online!";
}

?>
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($json);` say?

Comment: @Progman it dumps correctly with the respective information..

Comment: For example, it dumped this: object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["stream"]=> NULL } but it says the stream is online

Comment: `$json->stream === "NULL"` explictly equalling a string of null seems super strange from an API

Answer (score 0):

For me, I write as follows.

```
    if (empty($http_response_header)){
        echo "Stream is Offline!\n";
    } else {
        echo "Stream is Online!\n";
    }
```

Note: `$http_response_header` is not empty when first request was succeeded then second request was failed, so you should need to empty `$http_response_header` before each requests.

```
$http_response_header = '';
file_get_contents(...);
```

Comment: Being unable to communicate with an API isni't indictaive of the stream state is it?

Comment: @Scuzzy, you are 100% right, however in other cases, I think you should look at `$ http_response_header`. For example, when an error occurs in `json_decode` or when the response type is `application/xml`.